# Unresponsive button in jQuery; takes a long time to respond and reload

Tags: jquery

I have a button in jQuery: it's purpose is to show and hide a small block of text for the user on it's activation.
Here is the full website: https://gist.github.com/1616366

And here is the jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("p#derp").hide();
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("p#derp").slideDown("medium");
                $("button").click(function() {
                    $("p#derp").hide();
                    });
        });
    });
```

It WORKS, yes, but you have to wait about 3 seconds before it can be pushed and activated again.
I tried making another $document.ready(function() }); round the button.click function and hide, but it just doesn't seem to get the problem solved.

Comment: Did you try setting the `slideDown()` function to a faster speed?

Comment: Don't bind a `click` handler in another `click` handler...

Comment: Also, your markup is [very broken](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use something similar to the following:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    if($("p#derp").is(":visible")) {
        $("p#derp").stop(0, 0).hide();
    } else {
        $("p#derp").stop(0, 0).show();
    }
});
```

Note that I cannot remember what you have to put in the `stop` function, but a quick Google should tell you what should be used in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Make this paragraph hidden (`style="displan: none;"`) like that:

```
<p id='derp' style="displan: none;"> In this homework assignment, we had to make this website and compare two programs in different language to see the key differences between ActionScript and Java</p>
```

... and change your JavaScript to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $('p#derp').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```